# juju-scaleway specify the ssh key to use?

Tags: ssh, juju

I'm looking to leverage the new juju-scaleway charm following some of the documentation: 
https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/config-scaleway

I have a separate SSH key for my scaleway work, and I want to leverage that key to enable connections, but I'm unable to determine where I can specify the private key to use.   I can see where you can send public key information but I was hoping to use a different key than my default.

Is there an option to say
ssh-private-key: ~/.ssh/my-other-key.rsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the answer to this - it is as simple as ssh-add to add the given key to the chain.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-other-key.rsa
```

and then

```
juju scaleway bootstrap
```

it no longer asked for the 'root' user.